# How to run this python program?

Tags: windows-10, python

I want to ask how to run this program https://github.com/JungWinter/file-on-blockchain. Inside in the link is instruction but I do not understand everything. Can somebody here help me?

Comment: What exactly you do not understand?

Comment: honestly? I am new in coding in python and building blockchain. So I need to know what tools I need and how to run this program on my pc.

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: Thank romeo i try it... so the first step is to have the right operating system. And than?

Comment: The next step is to follow the instructions in github :)

Comment: yes right :) but try to help me with at least 3 and 4 instructions. How to run these scripts in Linux. Will I open a Ubuntu terminal and type a command?
1. git clone https://github.com/JungWinter/file-on-blockchain.
2.cd file-on-blockchain / blockchain
3 ../ init.sh
4 ../ start.sh

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the instructions, this is written to work on linux, and not windows 10.

You could try to use the WSL using the instructions at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 and see if that works for you. Other than that, you could try a virtual machine and run linux in that.

Comment: thx ... now I have another problem. In instructions is that part:
Create account for deploying
1.Open another terminal and move to file-on-blockchain/blockchain
2.geth attach ./chain-data/geth.ipc
3.In console, personal.newAccount() and enter password
4.miner.start() and miner.stop()

and I have problem with second instruction what is it? and when i get in to terminal it write me : command not found

Comment: It sounds like that before you start running programs and using python, you should look at how linux works and learn some of the basics. If you do, then the instructions in the link you posted will all make a lot more sense